# Android BOOT_COMPLETED Broadcast malfunction

Tags: android

I dont receive the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast when I test from my phone HUAWEI p6. **The Broadcast is received only once after install**

Here is AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
....
<receiver android:name=".receiver.WakefulBootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".receiver.AlarmNotificationReceiver">
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".receiver.MyWakefulReceiver">
    </receiver>
```

BootReceiver:

```
public class WakefulBootReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
public static String CALLER_ID = "WakefulBootReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Alog.debug("WakefulBootReceiver Before IntentService");
    Intent service = new Intent(context, AlarmSetService.class);
    service.putExtra("SERVICE_CALLER", CALLER_ID);
    startWakefulService(context, service);
}
}
```

And IntentService:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Alog.debug("AlarmSetService/onHandleIntent");
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String caller = "";
    if (extras != null) {
        caller = extras.getString("SERVICE_CALLER");
    }

    checkForTodayAlarms();

    if (caller.equals("MyWakefulReceiver")) {
        Alog.debug("AlarmSetService/caller MyWakefulReceiver");
        MyWakefulReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    } else {
        Alog.debug("AlarmSetService/caller WakefulBootReceiver");
        WakefulBootReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
```

It works on emulator. And works on phone when I send the broadcast with:

> ./adb shell
>
> > am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED

I opened the app several times before reboot. 
Is installed on device.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Try removing `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />` from the intent filter

Comment: Have the same behavior. Updated the description

Comment: Adding the WAKE_LOCK permission **and** removing the line of code @Karakuri mentioned, the boot complete portion of your code is working on my Nexus 5.

Comment: Hi. If you restart the device 2-3 times. Always receive the boradcast?? Thanks

Comment: Sometimes I need to wait up to 30 seconds after the boot has completed before it comes through but I always get the broadcast.

Comment: Just tried the simplest WakefulBroadcastReceiver and bootreceiver. I can confirm that is not working properly on this phone (Only **first** boot is caught). I checked other phones and the app is working Ok. I installed startup Manager and BootManager, and every boot app have same permission and installed on same path... Stuck here

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html), a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` requires the WAKE_LOCK permission. For what you are doing, a regular `BroadcastReceiver` should be sufficient. Something like this:

```
public class WakefulBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Make sure we are getting the right intent
        if( "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            // Your code here
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Received unexpected intent " + intent.toString());   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi blackcj. I think, according to documentation and training [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#wakeful). If I use an IntentService on broadcastreceive, needs to use "WakefulBroadcastReceiver" to secure background process